# How to customize icon for Wix custom bootstrapper

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to use different icons for my setup.exe (top-leftmost corner of the installer window) and Add/Remove Programs. In my Bundle.wxs, I used `<Bundle ... IconSourceFile='path\to\product1.ico'>` but when I set the value there it is applying to both places as described in its documentation. So I tried this in my Product.wxs `<Icon Id="ProductIcon" SourceFile="path\to\product2.ico"/> <Property Id='ARPPRODUCTICON' Value='ProductIcon'/>` in an attempt to override the declaration in Bundle, but it still shows the first icon in Add/Remove programs. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: In your <MsiPackage> element, what if you add Visible="yes" and reinstall the bundle? This should make the bundle icon and the MSI icon both show up in Add/Remove Programs. Are they now different?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The solution is to change Logo attribute of custom BA main window.

Comment: What does this mean? Some code would have been nice.