# Wix icon in Add/Remove programs

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using Wix to create my installer.
According to the official [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/configure_arp_appearance.html), if I want to change the icon in Add/Remove Programs, I need to add this:

```
<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="MySourceFiles\icon.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
```

But it does not works, the icon is not changed and I also get the following warning:

> C:\Users\rsheink\home\repos\tenlira\10Lira\TestWiXProject\Product.wxs(137,0):
>   warning LGHT1076: ICE36: Icon Bloat. Icon icon.ico is not used in the
>   Class, Shortcut, or ProgID table and also not used for ARPPRODUCTICON
>   property.

What am I missing please?

Thanks. Refael.

**Edit:**
Following the excelent advice from @harper, here is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:difx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DifxAppExtension">

  <Product Id="*" Codepage="1252" Language="1033" Manufacturer="Intel Corporation"
           Name="TenLira" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE" Version="31.00.0000">

    <Package Comments="Contact:  Your local administrator" Description="TenLira" InstallerVersion="500"
             Compressed="yes"
             InstallScope="perMachine"
             Keywords="Installer,MSI,Database" Languages="1033" Manufacturer="Intel Corporation" Platform="x64" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="my_application.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="no"
                  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no"
                  Disallow="no"
                  IgnoreRemoveFailure="no"
                  MigrateFeatures="yes"
                  Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
                  DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed" />

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="PROGRAMFILESSUBDIR" Name="Intel Corporation">
          <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="TenLira">
            <Directory Id="kmgl" Name="kmgl">
              <Directory Id="kmgl_win10" Name="kmgl_win10" />
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="tools" Name="tools" />
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <DirectoryRef Id="tools">

      <Component Id="devcon.exe" Guid="*">
        <File Id="devcon.exe" Source="..\tools\devcon\amd64\devcon.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>

    </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="TenLira" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="devcon.exe" />
    </Feature>

    <!--It should set the icon in Add/Remove programs, but it does not works and I don't know why.-->
    <Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="..\TenLira icons\coins\coins.ico" />
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTION" Value="icon.ico" />

  </Product>

</Wix>
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing any kind of reference. This calls for a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Unfortunately the FireGiant help doesn't show more than you did.

Comment: Just tried this in WiX 3 - I didn't see any problems, are you in WiX 4?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, I use Wix version 3.11

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I think it is just a minor typo in the property name. Typos do sneak into WiX sources - it is fiddly, but once you get it set up you will be happy with it. Thanks for the excellent source sample, it was quick to tweak for building.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Thank you very much!!! That solved the problem. Yes!!! I love you!!! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to mark your answer as the right answer.

Comment: Glad that solved the problem! Once you get the WiX source stable, you will likely never see such problems again. I never knew there were issues with accepting answers and reputation - weird design. Not to worry, problem solved. Btw, I am not 100% sure devcon.exe is redistributable? Maybe it is not a problem. Not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Request***: Please comment if any of the below works for you - and also if you did something else (as well) to get things working.

> **Quick List First**:
>
> - Is **`ARPPRODUCTICON`** spelled correctly?
> - Does the **`File.ico`** file have a hidden file extension? Example: **`icon.ico.bmp`** - **[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67896367/129130)**.
>
>   - **`Show file extensions in Windows Explorer`**
>   - Open a **`cmd.exe`** in the folder and do a dir to check?
> - Icon file problems:
>
>   - Is that a proper *.ico file? Try to save a normal *.bmp and rename the extension to *.ico. That should work for a rudimentary test icon.
>   - Find a proper template *.ico file for testing (there should be plenty
>     in your Visual Studio installation folder).

---

**UPDATE**:

Please try to change this:

```
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTION" Value="icon.ico" />
```

into this:

```
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
```

I will leave the original answer below since the setup.exe issue might be relevant for others.

And **one more thing**: I was told that the dialog set `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />` is the better one in the available WiX templates. I have no hard facts apart from that recommendation though. I haven't used `<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />` - just if it can save you some time.

---

**Old Answer**:

This might just be a **uppercase / lowercase issue**. As in `icon.ico` instead of `Icon.ico`.

Correct:

```
<Icon Id="Icon.ico" SourceFile="MySourceFiles\Icon.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="Icon.ico" />
```

Wrong:

```
<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="MySourceFiles\icon.ico"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="Icon.ico" />
```

During my testing I get the warning though, but the icon does work in Add/Remove Programs either way. **Are you making a setup.exe bundle**?

When you make a **setup.exe bootstrapper bundle**, you have to set the `IconSourceFile` attribute of the [Bundle Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bundle.html).

A link for safekeeping: [How to customize icon for Wix custom bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938620/how-to-customize-icon-for-wix-custom-bootstrapper).

Comment: 1. I checked and double checked, its not an uppercase / lowercase. 2. I am making an msi file, not a bundle.

Comment: Try to point to another ico file to see if there is something wrong with your current ico file?

Comment: Asmul, tried changing for a different .ico file, no success.