# WIX Icon doesnt work properly

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

I have the WIX script:

```
<Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="1" />
<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="{MY PATH}"/>
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
<Property Id="FINDPUBLICDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id="Registry" Type="raw" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)" Name="Location"/>
</Property>
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

<FeatureRef Id="Feature" />

</Product>
```

Everything works fine, but my Icon is still default at the Add/Remove Programs.

(Path is OK because, if i set wrong/not existed path i get compilation error)

(i tried to change `InstallerVersion` but nothing was happend)

Does anyone know what can be wrong ?

Comment: Did you get this fixed Vadim?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul thanks, but no, your answer, did not help, i tried it all and i am still searching solution

Comment: I would check the finished MSI with `Orca`, checking the `Icon table` to see that the correct entry is there, and if it is try to extract the icon file to verify it.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul thanks, i have to try, I'll let you know, if it help

Comment: @SteinÅsmul "Orca" shows that table "Icon" is present, then i has been export binary data from there to file, and file size is the same with my *.ico file

Comment: Are you installing an MSI only, or is it an MSI installing as part of a WiX bundle?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul MSI only, i use msiexec.exe via cmd.exe, to install it

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Hi, it's me again, do you have any minds about it or maybe you need some additional info ?

Comment: I would need to see the MSI. Have you tried this MSI on another computer to see if the same problem occurs there?

Comment: If you have used [**this approach**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/configure_arp_appearance.html) in your MSI, and you have made sure the `*.ico file` is valid and you have tried to install it outside your bundle (run the `MSI` itself, not the `setup.exe` bundle), then I don't know what is wrong. So please verify that you have done that (run MSI and check Add / Remove Programs).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul no, it didn't help, i wanna create new project with nothing except icon and some text files, to test it, if it will not help, i will send you it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

***Typo***: A common mistake is a typo in the property name, as you can see here: [Wix icon in Add/Remove programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689641/wix-icon-in-add-remove-programs/48693909#48693909), but this is not the case here (*this info added for others who experience the same problem and find your question*).

***Ico File***: As to this case, is that a hard coded path to the icon file? Is the path to an EXE file containing an icon? As I recall you need a proper `*.ico` file, and not an executable to point to. Haven't worked with this in a while and can't test at the moment, but give that a go: make sure you point to a real `*.ico` file. You can extract the ico file using Visual Studio. Open the file as a resource (File => Open => now specify resource). [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_xcKg7WM4Y).

***Bundle***: Are you installing via a bundle? If so, the ARP icon is specified for the bundle and not (just) for the MSI: [Bundle Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bundle.html). `IconSourceFile` attribute (see links - to the bundle element and also below).

---

Some links for safekeeping:

- [WIX Installer not displaying the custom image of WixUI Dialog correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965974/wix-installer-not-displaying-the-custom-image-of-wixui-dialog-correctly) (links to good bundle samples)
- [How to customize icon for Wix custom bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938620/how-to-customize-icon-for-wix-custom-bootstrapper?noredirect=1&lq=1) (what ARP icons are shown? The one for the bundle or the one for the MSI?)

Comment: it's easy to make a typo. for who comes here. check the spelling:
"ARP" + "PRODUCT" + "ICON"